# How to unflatten a nodes array object to a nested object which represents a directory structure

Tags: javascript, tree, hierarchy, flatten

How do you write a function that will perform an unflattening transformation on a nodes array of objects which represents a directory structure or routing path tree. Also, should any paths involve creation of empty nodes, how do you create these nodes for the result structure. The empty directories have their path and children keys only. Here's an example nodes array:

For example, if `nodes = [{id: 50, path: "/apple/banana"}]`, return

```
{
  "path": "/",
  "children": [
    {
      "path": "/apple",
      "children": [
        {
          "id": 50,
          "path": "/apple/banana",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have this:

```
const tree = { path: '/', children:[] }
const sortedNodes = nodes.sort((a, b) => (a.path.split('/').length - b.path.split('/').length));
sortedNodes.forEach(node => {
  const dirs = node.path.split('/').slice(1)
  let traversed = tree // Hold the reference of tree

  dirs.forEach((dir) => {
    const foundChild = traversed.children.find(child => child.path.split('/').slice().pop() === dir)
    foundChild ? traversed = foundChild : traversed.children.push({ path: node.path, id: node.id, children: [] });   
  })
})
console.log(tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the path and get parts for iterating the nested objects.

```js
var nodes = [{ id: 50, path: "/apple/banana" }],
    tree = nodes
        .reduce((t, { id, path }) => {
            path.split(/\//).reduce((r, _, i, p) => {
                var path = p.slice(0, i + 1).join('/') || '/';
                    temp = r.children.find(q => q.path === path);
                if (!temp) r.children.push(temp = { path, children: [] });
                return temp;
            }, t).id = id;
            return t;
        }, { children: [] })
       .children;

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```